# How do I add methods to nodejs supertest module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, supertest

I'm trying to add some convenience methods to https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest. So far the only way I was able do it is by adding them directly to the module source code in lib/test.js:

```
Test.prototype.expectHeaders = function (a)
{
  for (var header in a)
  {
    this._asserts.push(this._assertHeader.bind(this,
    {
      name: '' + header,
      value: a[header]
    }));
  }

  return this;
};
```

I tried via util.inherits and prototype.__proto__ but every attempt ends with "expectHeaders is not a function" exception.

Here is my latest attempt:

```
var supertest = require('supertest'),
  util = require('util');

var SccTest = function()
{
};

SccTest.prototype.__proto__ = supertest.prototype;

SccTest.expectHeaders = function (a)
{
  for (var header in a)
  {
    this._asserts.push(this._assertHeader.bind(this,
    {
      name: '' + header,
      value: a[header]
    }));
  }

  return this;
};

util.inherits(SccTest, supertest);
module.exports = SccTest;
```

How can I properly add methods to Test prototype?

Answer (score 0):

if you want inherited from supertest object, you don't need to point your prototype to supertest manually. you can just call util.inherites method :

```
var supertest = require('supertest'),
    util = require('util');

var SccTest = function(){
};
util.inherits(SccTest, supertest);

SccTest.prototype.expectHeaders = function (a){
  ...
};
module.exports = SccTest;
```

Comment: Doesn't work. I did scctest = require('./scctest'); scctest('http://www.google.com').get('/'); throws Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this code should be helpful.

```
   var supertest = require('supertest'),
      util = require('util');
    var SccTest=function (arguments) {
      var sccTest = {}
      sccTest.__proto__ = supertest(arguments)
      sccTest.expectHeaders = function (a)
      {
        for (var header in a)
        {
          this._asserts.push(this._assertHeader.bind(this,
          {
            name: '' + header,
            value: a[header]
          }));
        }
        return this;
      };
      return sccTest;
    }
```